# Align Text in Top Left

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm working with fullPage.js and I wanted to make some text sit around the top. I expected `margin-right` and `margin-top` to work and I even tried `vertical-align`. They didn't work.

Here is my code.

```css
.s1a {
  background: url(/https://www.well-played.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/ps5-play-has-no-limits-video-thumb-01-en-11jun20.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.s1a h1 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha512-4rPgyv5iG0PZw8E+oRdfN/Gq+yilzt9rQ8Yci2jJ15rAyBmF0HBE4wFjBkoB72cxBeg63uobaj1UcNt/scV93w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="fullPage">

        <div class="section s1a">
            <h1>At **Removed**, we truly believe that</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha512-gSf3NCgs6wWEdztl1e6vUqtRP884ONnCNzCpomdoQ0xXsk06lrxJsR7jX5yM/qAGkPGsps+4bLV5IEjhOZX+gg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>

        new fullpage('#fullPage', {
            autoScrolling: true
        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```css
    position: absolute;
    left: x%;
    top: y%;
```

where x and y are % from left and top

Answer (score 0):

Floating the text to left may be helpful in this case.

```css
*{
margin=0;
padding=0;
}
#fullPage {
  background: url('https://www.well-played.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/ps5-play-has-no-limits-video-thumb-01-en-11jun20.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#fullPage h1 {
  float : left;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha512-4rPgyv5iG0PZw8E+oRdfN/Gq+yilzt9rQ8Yci2jJ15rAyBmF0HBE4wFjBkoB72cxBeg63uobaj1UcNt/scV93w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="fullPage">
            <h1>At **Removed**, we truly believe that</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha512-gSf3NCgs6wWEdztl1e6vUqtRP884ONnCNzCpomdoQ0xXsk06lrxJsR7jX5yM/qAGkPGsps+4bLV5IEjhOZX+gg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>

        new fullpage('#fullPage', {
            autoScrolling: true
        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Make element position absolute with top and left value#
```

```css
.s1a {
  background: url(/https://www.well-played.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/ps5-play-has-no-limits-video-thumb-01-en-11jun20.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.s1a h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha512-4rPgyv5iG0PZw8E+oRdfN/Gq+yilzt9rQ8Yci2jJ15rAyBmF0HBE4wFjBkoB72cxBeg63uobaj1UcNt/scV93w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="fullPage">

        <div class="section s1a">
            <h1>At **Removed**, we truly believe that</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha512-gSf3NCgs6wWEdztl1e6vUqtRP884ONnCNzCpomdoQ0xXsk06lrxJsR7jX5yM/qAGkPGsps+4bLV5IEjhOZX+gg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>

        new fullpage('#fullPage', {
            autoScrolling: true
        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```